# What is your favorite car sound?

Tags: car, engine, sounds

I have been navigating the archives of SSD and noticed that a lot of people have posted queries about their favorite sounds from films. I am always fascinated with how we make these sounds and what has inspired us to come up with new and unique ways of affecting the audience by adding in an X factor to a common, everyday sound such as a car engine.

Woulds be interested to know what is your favorite cinematic car sound and why? Mine is the Evil Van/Truck from Jeepers Creepers. It seems to be a combo of an 18 wheeler, some animal growl, old machinery squeaking and creaking. Could be wrong, but is definitely frightening. Also, the POV shots of the evil presence from "The Evil Dead". I know that this is not a vehicle but they did record the motorcycle that the camera was mounted on and then pitched it down to amplify the low ends. Great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's a small bit in the opening of Safe House, when the car Denzel is in with the other guy and (as I recall, it's been a while) there's an intersection impact wherein the car gets T-boned.  The car rev spins up to a hard stop right by the camera.  That spin rev engine still sticks out as a favorite vehicle moment for me.  But in all seriousness, the entire vehicle chase sequence early on in the film (the one with mayhem on the freeway) is ridiculous in a good way, one of the longest and most intense car sequences I've seen (and heard).

Answer (score 1):

Mine would be Kurt Russel's Chevy Nova in Death Proof.  Harry Cohen did an amazing job making that car sound like pure danger!  From the low gurgling idle to the full out revs and bys.  I get goose bumps every time I watch the movie.

Answer (score 1):

Mini cooper, the Italian Job (the original movie and car)

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked the sound of the Mini in the Bourne Identity film, just because the sound is so hyper-real.

Answer (score 0):

[The last V8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiNZbcEzogU) - Mad Max Series.

Answer (score 0):

For a real car, my mind goes to Marty's big pickup in the *Back to the Future* movies. Maybe not the most interesting, but the drag racing scene when Marty revs at a red light against Biff is definitely iconic in my mind.

For a surreal car, I have to admit that the Tumbler and Bat Pod in *Batman Begins* and *The Dark Knight* are wickedly cool. I love what they do with shepherd tones during acceleration.

~Matt